# How to pass an array of checkboxes to a knockout custom binding?

Tags: arrays, checkbox, knockout.js, custom-binding

i'm using knockout 2.2.1.
I have a set of 3 check boxes to concatenate to get the corresponding values all together:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="top-colours" data-bind="topColoursLabel: { topColoursRed,topColoursBlue,topColoursGreen }">
    <legend>Top Colours:</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="top-colours-red" data-bind="checked: topColoursRed" id="tc-check-1" />
    <label for="tc-check-1">Red stripes</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="top-colours-blue" data-bind="checked: topColoursBlue" id="tc-check-2" />
    <label for="tc-check-2">Blue stripes</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="top-colours-green" data-bind="checked: topColoursGreen" id="tc-check-3" />
    <label for="tc-check-3">Green stripes</label>
</fieldset>
```

The result shall be for example: "Red stripes, Blue stripes".
My viewmodel is as follows:

```
function ColoursViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.template = "coloursView";
    self.topColoursRed = ko.observable(false);
    self.topColoursBlue = ko.observable(false);
    self.topColoursGreen = ko.observable(false);
    self.topColoursDescription = ko.observable("");
}
```

How shall be the custom bindings to achieve this?
I try something like that:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.topColoursLabel = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        // ...
        var checkText = '...';
        viewModel.topColoursDescription(checkText);
    }
};
```

I'm not able to find out how to pass the array to my custom bindings to subscribe to the values of the 3 check boxes, because I'm noob to knockout.

It seems to me, that a declaration like:

```
data-bind="topColoursLabel: { topColoursRed,topColoursBlue,topColoursGreen }"
```

would be great to achieve this, but i'm searching the right way to do that.

Note: i cannot use a computed observable here, because i need to get some other properties from element - i mean the label-for text - so a custom binding is needed.

Can someone help?

UPDATED jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sx87j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, custom binding handler is not what you really need. You should implement your `self.coloursDescription` as `computed` observable which will track checkbox changes and return currently selected stripes:

```
self.topColoursDescription = ko.computed(function(){
    var colors = [];
    if (self.topColoursRed())   colors.push('Red stripes');
    if (self.topColoursBlue())  colors.push('Blue stripes');
    if (self.topColoursGreen()) colors.push('Green stripes');
    return colors.join(', ');
});
```

Also remove all tracks of your custom bindings from markup and you will get something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/h7Bmb/8/

**Update**

I can make your updated fiddle to work with *top colours*. Making it work with *bottom colors* too looks a bit complicated with your current approach.

Enumerate all linked color observables in your binding:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="top-colours" data-bind="topColoursLabel: [ topColoursRed, topColoursBlue, topColoursGreen ]">
```

Change your custom binding code (the line where `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` is called):

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(valueAccessor(), ko.utils.unwrapObservable);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Sx87j/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason of the custom binding is, that i would avoid to hard-code the text of the label. So, it seems to me that i need the custom binding parameter element, to find out the related label-for.

Comment: Since you don't want label captions hard-coded, I assume that you get these captions from an external data? May be there is a sence to represent all colors (with captions) as JS-array and output them through `foreach` binding.

Comment: Hi, i assume you are interested to the workflow, but this has been already fixed.
FYI: the GUI is created using JQM, in many different languages (ENU, FRA...), so i don't put the text of the labels in the data model. My custom binding shall be like a kind of "adapter" between the GUI and the data/business logic. This workflow has some other more advantages.

The updated fiddle actually display the selected labels as expected, but react only to changes to the first checkbox. 
I'm not able to get the function reacting to all 3 observables, and i think its more knockout related question.